# Initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type error in objective-c/cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In order to print out something in file, I have the following code.

```
FILE *fp = fopen(cString, "w+");
NSString* message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@":SLEEP: %@:%@\n", ...];
char* cMessage = [message UTF8String]; <--  warning 
fprintf(fp, cMessage); <-- warning
fclose(fp);
```

However, I got `Initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type error` in `char* cMessage`, and `Format not a string literal and no format  argument` warning.

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: I suggest switching to Clang in your Xcode build settings, as it gives clearer warning and error messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-UTF8String` returns a `const char *`, but you're assigning it into a `char *`.  As such, you're discarding the `const` qualifier.

As for `fprintf`, you should probably be doing:

```
fprintf(fp, "%s", cMessage);
```